Slow __repr__ calculation for one of Python classes slows down the jupyter notebook debugger in VSCode
I am trying to debug some code in VSCode Jupyter Notebook.
I get the following warning:
pydevd warning: Computing repr of Out (dict) was slow (took 6.62s)
Customize report timeout by setting the `PYDEVD_WARN_SLOW_RESOLVE_TIMEOUT` environment variable to a higher timeout (default is: 0.5s)

And every step-over in the debugger takes really long time.
As I understand it, the debugger tries to automatically resolve repr of all currently defined variables, even if I am not asking it to print anything.
I've tried to disable automatic variable resolution following the advice here.
I've tried setting environment variables such as PYDEVD_WARN_SLOW_RESOLVE_TIMEOUT and PYDEVD_DISABLE_VARIABLE_LOOKUP, either in jupyter notebook or in the debug session itself.
None of the above helped.
Reproducible example:
import time

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
    
    def __repr__(self):
        time.sleep(5)

c1 = MyClass("asd")
c2 = MyClass("bcd")
c3 = MyClass("bcd2")

The debugger "hands" if you break beyond initialization of "c1".
I've also noted that there is a problem only when I use Jupyter Notebook in VSCode. Running python debugger for a script with similar code doesn't hand (after hiding "variables" section, at least).

Can you provide a [mre]? It would help with testing solutions.
